# The reputation for meta.UX channel and UX.SE channel differs by 10

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have just observed that the reputation in my main UX.SE account is 41 and after refreshing the meta.UX site several times, it is showing 31. Why is it so ?

Is this expected behavior ?

Comment: To use a cliche, it's just caching. Both the Meta and main site are showing the same reputation now.

Comment: Yes actually, it is showing after half an hour nearly. Is it take that much time to sync with each other ?

Comment: Doesn't sound out of line with what I've experienced. Reputation on meta is "less important" so I'm pretty sure it has a *much* slower update frequency than on the main site.

Answer (score 2):

As @JonW pointed out and as you noticed yourself, it just takes a bit to synchronize.